# no crank, no start, no power

Tags: ford, starting, focus, no-crank-no-start

2016 Ford Focus. Ran when I bought it, but had been hit in the passenger side. While the doors were off, it randomly started acting funny when running. The display would start flashing then the car would die. The headlights would not always turn off. We thought it was due to the door sensor and we unhooked the battery to preserve it. The car ran to get to the body shop where they cut out and welded in part of the rear quarter panel. After they were done with the repair and paint, the car would not start. There is no dome light, no dash display, no bell when the key is in, nothing happens when the key is turned. The radio does turn on. If the button on the shifter is depressed when the radio is on, the display says "transmission not in park". We have tested all the relays, the battery is charged, all of the fuses look intact, there is no corrosion visible on any of the connections. We connected a scanning tool and it couldn’t even “find” the car.
There is no warranty

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! It sounds to me like your ECU could be toast, though I wouldn't suggest you run down to the Ford dealership and purchase a new one. I don't have any idea on how you might be able to test it, other than a replacement.

Comment: there's no communication with any module? you need to confirm power and ground with any modules in the car and go from there. and use a multimeter to test your fuses.

Comment: Troubleshooting a No Start, No Spark, No Fuel, No Com (any car):  https://youtu.be/lx1dqoxiZ7Q

Comment: No crank, no start diagnosis (bad block ground) - Ford SHO: https://youtu.be/-fyKizH_oQ8